# CreateLinkedTokenSource: How to avoid dead code

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, cancellation, cancellationtokensource, cancellation-token

I try to implement a linked cancellation token and get a warning that the CancellationTokeSource is never null and dead code can be avoided.

```
public void Foo(CancellationToken cancellationToken , TimeSpan t) {
    using CancellationTokenSource timeout = new CancellationTokenSource(t);
    using CancellationTokenSource combined = CancellationTokenSource
        .CreateLinkedTokenSource(
            timeout.Token,
            cancellationToken);
    bar(combined.Token);
}
```

To be more specific: I get the CA1508 warning which suggests removing the conditions to avoid dead code. But the thing is, I don't see any conditions here. Am I missing something or can this warning be safely ignored?

Comment: [Open Roslyn Github Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3063) for this - Opened 12 days ago as a continuation from a previous version

Comment: You can ignore it, it's a false positive.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this open issue when doing my research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the solution from the two comments:
There is an open [Roslyn Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/3063) and the warning can safely be ignored